# Convert text to value hexadecimal

Tags: perl, arabic

I'm trying to put the word (for sale) "عربي" in Arabic. But my terminal reverses itself from left to right. Knowing that Arabic is written from right to left. the word is equivalent to "llbye" but the terminal writes "eybll" (ﻊﻴﺒﻠﻟ).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

binmode( STDOUT, ':utf8' );

use Encode qw< encode decode >;

my $str = 'ﻟﻠﺒﻴﻊ';    # "for sale"
my $enc = encode( 'UTF-8', $str );
my $dec = decode( 'UTF-8', $enc );

my $decoded = pack 'U0W*', map +ord, split //, $enc;

print "Original string : $str\n";     #  ل ل ب ي ع
print "Decoded string 1: $dec\n";      #  ل ل ب ي ع
print "Decoded string 2: $decoded\n"; #  ل ل ب ي ع
my $k = reverse($decoded);
print "Decode  reverse : $k\n";
print "0x$_" for unpack "H*", scalar reverse "$decoded\n";
```

On line 21, I'm trying to better visualize converting these characters to hexdump, but I receive:

`Character in 'H' format wrapped in unpack at line 21.`

Term[Perl]:# perl schreib.pl
Original string : ﻟﻠﺒﻴﻊ
Decoded string 1: ﻟﻠﺒﻴﻊ
Decoded string 2: ﻟﻠﺒﻴﻊ
Decode  reverse : ﻊﻴﺒﻠﻟ

Character in 'H' format wrapped in unpack at line 21.
Character in 'H' format wrapped in unpack at line 21.
Character in 'H' format wrapped in unpack at line 21.
Character in 'H' format wrapped in unpack at line 21.
Character in 'H' format wrapped in unpack at line 21
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDGh9.jpg)

As in the image, the first blank frame is what I copy and paste, and the terminal inverts without my permission. having to use reverse to print from right to left as in the second frame, as it should have been when pasted.
How do I transform these characters into hexadecimal?

Comment: Converting the output in Perl is fine, but I typically just pipe the output to a tool such as hexdump that will do it for me. That would be raw UTF-8 and not the fancy character stuff that @ikegami shows.

Comment: I looked into the bidi (bi-directional) stuff for my favorite terminal, iTerm2, but it doesn't support bidi yet. the [issue comments](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/1611) are very interesting though. Basically, your terminal needs to somehow support bidi text for this to work out for Arabic where order matters for the proper ligatures.

Comment: Microsoft's terminal has an [open issue for bidi](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/538)

Comment: Just fyi you wrote the wrong word the first time in the question. You wrote "Arab" instead of "for sale" in this sentence: "I'm trying to put the word (for sale) "عربي""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unpack H*` expects a string of bytes (characters with value 00..FF), but you have a string of Unicode Code Points (characters with value 000000..10FFFF).

You can use

```perl
sprintf "%vX", $str
```

which is effectively the same as

```perl
join ".", map sprintf( "%X", ord( $_ ) ), split //, $str
```

and

```perl
join ".", map sprintf( "%X", $_ ), unpack "W*", $str
```

All three work for any string (bytes, UCP, whatever).

For `$str`, `$dec` and `$decoded`, the above produces

```
FEDF.FEE0.FE92.FEF4.FECA
```

For `$enc`, the above produces

```
EF.BB.9F.EF.BB.A0.EF.BA.92.EF.BB.B4.EF.BB.8A
```

(You may get something different since our files might not be the same.)

---

With Unicode Code Points, we can use charnames (and/or Unicode::UCD) for more info.

```perl
use charnames qw( :full );
use feature qw( say );

for my $cp ( unpack "W*", $str ) {
   my $ch = chr( $ucp );
   if ( $ch =~ /(?[ \p{Print} - \p{Mark} ])/ ) {   # Not sure if good enough.
      printf "‹%s› ", $ch;
   } else {
      print "--- ";
   }

   printf "U+%X ", $ucp;

   say charnames::viacode( $ucp );
}
```

For `$str`, `$dec` and `$decoded`, the above produces

```
‹ﻟ› U+FEDF ARABIC LETTER LAM INITIAL FORM
‹ﻠ› U+FEE0 ARABIC LETTER LAM MEDIAL FORM
‹ﺒ› U+FE92 ARABIC LETTER BEH MEDIAL FORM
‹ﻴ› U+FEF4 ARABIC LETTER YEH MEDIAL FORM
‹ﻊ› U+FECA ARABIC LETTER AIN FINAL FORM
```

---

Data::Dumper with `local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` will produce ASCII output as well.